# Get AD user who is connected to SQL instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, active-directory, audit

How do I get the AD user which is connected to my SQL Server instance? The user is not connected using Windows Authentication, but with a SQL Server Login (who is shared among other people).

However, I need to know if there is a way to audit exactly who (in terms of AD user) is doing what with that SQL shared login.

Is it possible? Some system variable or system function and whatnot?

Comment: There is no correlation between SQL Authenticated logins and Active Directory.

Comment: So if the person connected is not using windows authentication, it is entirely impossible to catch him?

Comment: Not entirely sure about sql-server. In oracle we have that information stored in a view - `v$session`. Try checking if there is anything similar for `v$session` in sql-server. Google gave me this - ` sys.dm_exec_sessions` not sure, if ti will help.

Comment: How would you expect to correlate a sql server login, which can be something like "ThisISMyGoofyUserName" to "domain\SID"? Unless you keep a record of this correlation, I don't see how it's possible. I assume you are using a shared sql server login and this is the reason of this question, as you want to see who is using that joint account. In this case... you're question won't solve your problem.

Comment: You can see the host name user is connected from. That can probably tell you who it is?

Comment: "Catch" is an odd word. If you have two users on a shared SQL login and you want login auditing then give them two different logins. Easy solution. Sharing logins is a bad practice to begin with.